# ibm-datapower gives "&gt" in place of ">" and "&lt" in place of "<" in resulting XML for text data using XSLT

Tags: xslt, hex, ibm-datapower

In one of my application, I am trying to convert the response of my service with the help of xslt on datapower.
In one of the response scenario, I need to show an xml something like below:

```
<data contentType="text/xml;charset=utf-8" contentLength="80"><![CDATA[Your request cannot be processed]]></data>
```

But my XSLT fails on datapower and it shows `"&gt;"` and `"&lt;"` in place of `">"` and `"<"`.

Below are my some of the attempted templates. Kindly have a look and suggest any correction:

Attempt 1:Tried with `"&gt;`" and `"&lt;"`

```
<xsl:param name="mask"   select="'Your request cannot be processed'"/>

         <xsl:template match="*" mode="copyFault">
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;data contentType="text/xml;charset=utf-8" contentLength="80"&gt;&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>   
            <xsl:value-of select="$mask" />
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;&lt;/data&gt;</xsl:text>           
          </xsl:template>
```

Attempt 2:Tried with HEX values

```
<xsl:param name="mask"   select="'Your request cannot be processed'"/>
          <xsl:variable name="lessThan" select="'&#x3C;'"/>
          <xsl:variable name="GreaterThan" select="'&#x3E;'"/>

         <xsl:template match="*" mode="copyFault">
            <xsl:value-of  disable-output-escaping = "yes" select="$lessThan"/>
            <xsl:text>data contentType="text/xml;charset=utf-8" contentLength="80"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping = "yes" select="$GreaterThan"/>
            <xsl:value-of  disable-output-escaping = "yes" select="$lessThan"/>
            <xsl:text>![CDATA[</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$mask" />
            <xsl:text>]]</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping = "yes" select="$GreaterThan"/>
            <xsl:value-of  disable-output-escaping = "yes" select="$lessThan"/>
            <xsl:text>/data</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping = "yes" select="$GreaterThan"/>            
          </xsl:template>
```

Please let me know what should I do to get the xml in proper format from datapower.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way in XSLT to output a certain XML element is a literal result element so using

```
<data contentType="text/xml;charset=utf-8" contentLength="80">Your request cannot be processed</data>
```

in your XSLT will then output that element in the result. If you want to populate the element with a variable or parameter value then use e.g.

```
<data contentType="text/xml;charset=utf-8" contentLength="80"><xsl:value-of select="$mask"/></data>
```

If the XSLT processor is in charge of serializing the result to a file or string and you want some element like the `data` element to have a CDATA section as the content then declare e.g.  `<xsl:output cdata-section-elements="data"/>` as a child of `xsl:stylesheet` (or `xsl:transform` if you have named the root element that way).

Answer (score 0):

`disable-output-escaping` is a thoroughly nasty feature: it doesn't work on all processors, and if it's supported at all, it only works when the transformation output is fed directly into an XSLT-aware serializer, so it depends on how you are running the transformation.

It's much better to avoid `disable-output-escaping` when you can, and there's certainly no evidence you need it here. The requirement to output a CDATA section is somewhat unusual (any well-written application reading XML doesn't care whether the text is in a CDATA section or not), but if you really need it, then you can usually achieve it using `<xsl:output cdata-section-elements="data"/>`. (Though again, this only works if the output is fed into an XSLT-aware serializer.)

Certainly, generating start and end tags using `disable-output-escaping` is very poor practice.